# React Bootstrap datepicker issue with package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am having a major issue with my npm package installer.  It was working always but I removed the package-lock.json file, and just doesnt work at all now.  I cant seem to run it, all I can offer currently is my pakage.json file as shown below and my npm log, which gives the following error:

**Npm log**
[image]

**My package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@crystallize/react-growl": "^3.2.0",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "final-form": "^4.20.1",
        "final-form-arrays": "^3.0.2",
        "framer-motion": "^2.9.4",
        "google-map-react": "^2.1.8",
        "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
        "google-timezone-api": "^1.0.1",
        "i": "^0.3.6",
        "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
        "npm": "^6.14.8",
        "query-string": "^6.14.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
        "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "^5.1.0",
        "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^5.1.4",
        "react-content-loader": "^5.1.4",
        "react-create-class": "^1.0.0",
        "react-data-table": "^0.1.0",
        "react-data-table-component": "^6.11.5",
        "react-datepicker": "^3.3.0",
        "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
        "react-device-detect": "^1.14.0",
        "react-dropzone": "^11.2.3",
        "react-feather": "^2.0.8",
        "react-final-form": "^6.5.1",
        "react-final-form-file-field": "0.0.6",
        "react-google-places-autocomplete": "^3.0.0",
        "react-growl": "^0.1.2",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-image-crop": "^8.6.6",
        "react-lazyload": "^2.6.5",
        "react-leaflet": "^2.7.0",
        "react-notifications": "^1.7.2",
        "react-parallax": "^3.1.2",
        "react-phone-number-input": "^3.1.16",
        "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
        "react-select": "^3.1.0",
        "react-slick": "^0.27.12",
        "react-table": "^6.11.5",
        "react-table-v6": "^6.8.6",
        "react-toast-notifications": "^2.4.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "styled-components": "^5.2.0"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like i answered my own question with the following:

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

If anyone can shed a light on this on if this is safe to use on production and in the future as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's a version conflict between the version of `react-bootstrap` that you've specified in your package.json, and the version of `react-bootstrap` that `react-bootstrap-date-picker` specifies it needs.

Your package.json lists

`"react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2"`

In the latest `react-bootstrap-date-picker`, it lists

`"react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0"`

The carrot notation (`^`) allows npm to install the latest minor version (the second number in the three-part version string), but never change the major version number (first number in the version string). That means the `^0.31.0` version cannot be automatically increased to `1.0.0` (the next major version) or anything greater.

I'd suggest changing your package.json to specify: `"react-bootstrap": "^0.32.0"`. However, you should be aware that will install a fairly old version of `react-bootstrap`.

Alternatively, you may also want to look around for a newer date-picker package, as it doesn't look like `react-bootstrap-date-picker` has been updated in the last four years. It's relying on a older version of `react-bootstrap` (from ~4yrs ago). It's also probably very out of date compared to the latest versions of Bootstrap 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

react-bootstrap-date-picker is looking for a much older version of react-bootstrap than the one you have installed. The caret (^) only allows minor version updates. 0.x to 1.x is a major version update.

https://github.com/pushtell/react-bootstrap-date-picker/blob/master/package.json#L21

There isn't much you can do other than downgrade react-bootstrap, or replace react-bootstrap-date-picker with another library.

Comment: Thanks @user2867288 check out my solution on the bottom it resolved it, I just want to know if this is just a temporary hack.. or something else.

Comment: It's not ideal, you'll need to commit your package-lock.json to your repo if you aren't already and make sure that's managed properly during merges. I'd make it a priority to update your app so you don't have the conflicting peer dependency. Bug these guys to update their library! https://github.com/pushtell/react-bootstrap-date-picker/issues/170